# Why does a different result show up when filtering a date in google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm very new to programming so I'm not sure how to phrase this but in google sheets, I'm having a problem:
when filtering results using `=IFERROR(FILTER('Segment Management'!B:B,'Segment Management'!A:A=B5))`, it works perfectly fine with letters and numbers but when there's a date in `Segment Management` cell `B5` it instead of saying the date (in this case 15/3/2020) it outputs "43906". Could I get some help to explain why it says this number instead of the date?

Comment: Can you provide a spreadsheet that reproduces this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Date is considered as plain number in google sheets that's the reason you get numbers instead of date you can either do either of one

Select the column where you have put formula & in menu `Format> Number> and select date formatting`

**OR**

use this formula `=ARRAYFORMULA(TEXT(FILTER('Segment Management'!B:B,'Segment Management'!A:A=B5),"DD/MM/YYYY"))`